# What are infrastructure architecture options for distributed development teams using Visual Studio with TFS for .Net development

Tags: .net, infrastructure

So We have distributed development teams and use common TFS servers. What I am looking for is different options of architecture styles for distributed development. Combinations of development from desktops, virtual development terminals with TFS in one location or multi server(TFS) environment...
Thank you for your help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread:
[MS Team Foundation Server in distributed environments - hints tips tricks needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999/ms-team-foundation-server-in-distributed-environments-hints-tips-tricks-needed)

Answer (score 0):

You better use Mercurial, really..